# Why does the code formatting not work?

Tags: support

Why does the code formatting not work in this [edit](https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/382130)?

I tried to fix the quotes from files in the question, but somehow the 4-space prefix is ignored.

Answer (score 7):

You need 8 spaces for code formatting in lists.

```
1. This is a test

        With code
```

will display as:

1. This is a test

   ```
   With code
   ```

Comment: This makes sense. I was not aware that the code block will be still inside the list. I updated the edit request.